Wix visual studio project (msi) building with wrong name
I have a wix project that generates an output msi, inside the project i have set the output name using the  tag. But the msi get's built with the project name instead. The msi name also changes when i change the project name.
What could be the reason for this? I need to include the $(Platform) with the output name.

This is hard to answer without seeing your wixproj file.
Most likely you set the OutputName too early in your targets execution path.
What would definitely work is (Wix5):
<Target Name="SetOutputFileName" BeforeTargets="AssignTargetPaths">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetName>Yourname$(Platform)</TargetName>
  <TargetFileName>$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)</TargetFileName>
  <TargetPath>$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)</TargetPath>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>

or (Wix3x)
<Target Name="SetOutputFileName" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetName>Yourname$(Platform)$(TargetExt)</TargetName>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>

